# Zend 1.12: Append javascript to bottom of view

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

What do I use in the controller to append a javascript file to the end of a view?

I do not want to put it in the head, so `headScript()` and `headLink()` are out, but I cannot find a working example of what I'm looking for in either the Zend documentation or elsewhere.

I've tried using `$this->inlineScript()->appendFile('/js/myfile.js');`, but it throws an error saying `inlineScript()` doesn't exist.   I'm assuming its Zend 2 only.

Can someone point me in the right direction to a method that does what I'm asking for, or does it (oddly) not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
$this->view->InlineScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl() .'/js/myfile.js');
```

and in the bottom of youy layout add:

```
<?php
    echo $this->InlineScript(); 
?>
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Just had a moment of blanked mind, I suppose. )

Comment: I add a precision. If you haven't layout, add echo in your view. :)

Comment: It doesn't work.   I get a 404 on the file. Our js, like our css, is located in the `public` folder, and when I call the css all I need to do is `$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/mycss.css');`, so shouldn't it work the same way if the js folder is in the same directory?

Comment: try wihtout `$this->view->baseUrl() .` But may be it a .htaccess problem.

Comment: lol.   I'm such an idiot.  I'm so used to naming my javascript folders `js` that I didn't even register in my mind that whoever set up the directory named the folder `javascript`.   This works.   Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: You're welcomme. Happy for you! :D